# Find the $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is
$$
\text{adj} B = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         -45& 33& -28 \\
         32& -10& -16\\
        -4& -24& 2\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

If $\det B = −202$, then find the $3\times 3$ matrix $B$, whose adjoint is given as above.

First, I wrote the $3x3$ matrix as $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\
                                 d & e & f\\
                                 g & h & i\end{bmatrix}$$. Then I found the cofactor matrix and typed its transpose. As a result,
$$
\begin{cases}
-fh&+ei&=-45 \\
 -id&+fg&=32 \\
 dh&-eg&=-4 \\
 -ib&+ch&=33 \\
 ia&-cg&=-10 \\
 -ah&+bg&=-24 \\
 bf&-ec&=-28 \\
 -af&+cd&=-16 \\
 ea&-bd&=2
\end{cases}
$$

came from the transactions I made. Then I applied the determinant formulas and replaced what I had just found. $$\begin{cases}-45a+32b-4c=-202 \\
                 33d-10e-24f=-202\\ 
                -28g-16h+2i=-202\end{cases}$$   But I got stuck here. How can I find $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i$ here? I will be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 5):

$B^{-1} = \frac{adj(B)} {\det B} \implies B = \frac{(adj(B))^{-1}}{\det B} $

Can you do now?

Comment: Thank you very much :) I did :)

Comment: @Deniz you're welcome; you can show your appreciation by accepting the answer because it was the first ;)

Answer (score 1):

The adjugate satisfies the relation
$$
B\operatorname{adj}B=(\det B)I\qquad(*)
$$
and therefore, if $B$ is invertible,
$$
B=(\det B)(\operatorname{adj}B)^{-1}
$$
Your final linear system is part of the relation $(*)$, if you notice, but you forgot some equations.

With some patience, you get
$$
(\operatorname{adj}B)^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1/101 &  3/202 & -2/101 \\
     0 & -1/202 & -4/101 \\
-2/101 & -3/101 & -3/202
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much :) I did :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to solve it backward. See this solution, please.
Given

$ \mathbf {detB} = −202$, and

$
\mathbf{adj} B = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         -45& 33& -28 \\
         32& -10& -16\\
        -4& -24& 2\\
\end{array}
\right]
$,

then, $ \mathbf{B^{-1}} = \frac{1}{detB} . adjB$.

This implies that,
$\mathbf {B^{-1}} = -\frac{1}{202}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         -45& 33& -28 \\
         32& -10& -16\\
        -4& -24& 2\\
\end{array}
\right]
$.

Now take $\mathbf{B} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         a& b& c\\
         d& e& f\\
         g& h& i\\
\end{array}
\right]
$.

Using `invertibility relation`, $\mathbf{BB^{-1}} = \mathbf{B^{-1}B} = \mathbf{I}$, i.e.,
$$
-\frac{1}{202}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         -45& 33& -28 \\
         32& -10& -16\\
        -4& -24& 2\\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         a& b& c\\
         d& e& f\\
         g& h& i\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         1& 0& 0\\
         0& 1& 0\\
         0& 0& 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$.

Using `simple matrix multiplication`, you'll get the following system of equations by using $B^{-1}$ against the first, second, and third columns of the matrix $B$ in that order.

$$
 (\mathbf{1st}) \rightarrow
-\frac{1}{202}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         -45& 33& -28 \\
         32& -10& -16\\
        -4& -24& 2\\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         a\\
         d\\
         g\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
         1\\
         0\\
         0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
 (\mathbf{2nd}) \rightarrow
-\frac{1}{202}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         -45& 33& -28 \\
         32& -10& -16\\
        -4& -24& 2\\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         b\\
         e\\
         h\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
         0\\
         1\\
         0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

$$
 (\mathbf{3rd}) \rightarrow
-\frac{1}{202}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         -45& 33& -28 \\
         32& -10& -16\\
        -4& -24& 2\\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         c\\
         f\\
         i\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
         0\\
         0\\
         1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Now, you can multiply both sides, in each of the equations, by $-202$ to eliminate the $-\frac{1}{202}$. Then, solve the 3 equations to get the first, second, and third columns of the matrix $B$. If you solve it correctly, you'll get the matrix $B$ below
$$
\mathbf (1st) \rightarrow
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         a\\
         d\\
         g\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
         2\\
         0\\
         4\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$
\mathbf (2nd) \rightarrow
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         b\\
         e\\
         h\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
         -3\\
         1\\
         6\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$
\mathbf (3rd) \rightarrow
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         c\\
         f\\
         i\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
         4\\
         8\\
         3\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Hence,
$$
\mathbf B =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
         2& -3& 4 \\
         0& 1& 8\\
        4& 6& 3\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$